# how can I send dial-up message through external modem connected serial port?

Tags: c#, networking, modem, dial-up

I connect the external modem to the pc with serial port.
so i want to connect server through dial-up method with C#.
And then, send and receive message.

How can i solve this problem? please.

Can I use serialport component of .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
You'll need to find out from the server specs what type of message to send, but yes, you would use the SerialPort object.

Here's a starting point for you.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic35775.htm

And the Bing search I used to find it.

http://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+modem+communications+via+serialport&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC

Comment: thanks a lot. i referred link provided. and then i found AT Command for modem programming :). thank you again.